# Custom Tab Control Designer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Basically what I want to know how to do in .NET (preferably) VB.NET is how to be able to use a normal designer for my custom tab control object I created. I cannot seem to find anything that's exactly what I need. Here's the Class header:

```
Public Class InvoiceTabPage
    Inherits TabPage
```

[image]

This works, and I can use it as a tab page, add it to normal tab controls etc, however I am not able to move controls around in the designer because when I go to the design view it's just the list of all the contained controls. Does anyone know how to go about this? Please let me know if I need to clarify this more.

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance we could get a screenshot? Not that I don't believe you, but it'd be helpful for anyone with this question in the future to be able to go "Yup! That's what I'm getting too!"

Comment: @JeffBridgman I attached a screenshot of the designer, you can see all my controls for the tab page, but it's just not possible to design the control how I want. I've been searching for hours online... Any help would be appreciated, even if it's to confirm that's just the way it is.

Comment: That's the default component view, not fit to design the layout of a tab page.  You need to create your own TabControlDesigner and TabPageDesigner.  Very unpleasant because you cannot inherit the existing ones, they are internal.  And not trivial.  If you really want to pursue this then use a good decompiler to look at the existing ones.  Otherwise a very good reason to consider using UserControls instead of custom tab pages.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the response! For reference this works fine with a designer as a user control, as soon as I inherit TabPage I can no longer edit like this, which is a real shame. I definitely don't think it's worth it for me to go through all of that, I was reading about it earlier before posting on here and giving up on it. I'm just going to lay this one to rest and say that there's no easy solution to prevent this from happening.